¿Cómo funcionan los parámetros 2 y 3 de requestLocationUpdates?
Tengo una confusión con los parámetros 2 (tiempo) y 3 (distancia) del requestLocationUpdates.
¿El onLocationChanged() se ejecuta cuando los dos parámetros (2 Y 3) se cumplen o se ejecuta cuando se cumple uno de los dos parámetros (2 ó 3)?
He leído muchos ejemplos, en unos ejemplos dice que se deben cumplir los 2 parámetros y en otros ejemplos dice que cuando se cumpla uno de los dos parámetros.
¿Es posible parametrizar el requestLocationUpdatese para que solo lo afecte un parámetro, el 2 (tiempo) ó el 3 (distancia)?
Gracias

Me parece que la doc es clara. Traducción: Se llama cuando la ubicación ha cambiado y las ubicaciones se entregan en lotes. La implementación predeterminada llama a onLocationChanged() con todas las ubicaciones en el lote. Siempre se garantiza que la lista de ubicaciones no esté vacía y que esté ordenada desde la ubicación más antigua hasta la más reciente (de modo que la ubicación más antigua en el lote esté en el índice 0 en la lista y la ubicación más reciente en el lote esté en el índice 1 en la lista). O sea, se llamará siempre que cambie la ubicación en cualquiera de sus parámetros.

Ver enlace a la documentación.

Ok  A. Cedano, gracias
